# VBA code update from Outlook 2016 to 2013

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote this code on an other PC which had Win10 and Office 2016. It is used in an outlook rule. It saves the `xml` files from the e-mail to a folder and change it to `xlsx` file in an other folder. In Outlook 2016 it runs properly. I copied it to an other notebook.

This notebook has Win10 and Office 2013 and this code run in Outlook 2013 without any error message but the `xml` files neither were saved into the given folder and nor were converted to `xlsx`.

What could be wrong in this code?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub saveconvAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim dateFormat As String
Dim convFormat As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object

saveFolder = "C:\Users\tulaj\Documents\xml\"
convFolder = "C:\Users\tulaj\Documents\xls\"
dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd HH-mm-ss")

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.FileName

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(saveFolder)
    If UCase(Right(objAtt.FileName, Len(XML))) = UCase(XML) Then
        NewFileName = convFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.FileName & "_conv.xlsx"

Set ConvertThis = Workbooks.Open(saveFolder & dateFormat & objAtt.FileName)
        ConvertThis.SaveAs FileName:=NewFileName, FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        ConvertThis.Close
    End If
Next
Set objAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

In Tools-References are selected the falowings:

- Visual Basic For Aplications
- Microsoft Outlook 15.0 Object Library
- OLE Automation
- Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object Library
- Microsoft Scripting Runtime

Comment: Where is the variable `XML` defined?  (I assume it must be defined **somewhere** or it wouldn't have run in Office 2016.)

Comment: Have you check if the code was even started? Put a break point at first line and call it manually. Perhaps you should use `Environ("USERPROFILE")` instead of hard coded path.

Comment: @PatricK I can not put any break point in it. I don't know why. Even the F8 key step-by-step function doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you...

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub saveconvAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim SaveFolder As String
    Dim convFolder As String
    Dim DateFormat As String
    Dim ConvFormat As String
    Dim NewFileName As String
    Dim ConvertThis As Object
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object

    SaveFolder = "C:\Temp\xml\"
    convFolder = "C:\Temp\xls\"
    DateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd HH-mm-ss ")

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        Debug.Print objAtt.FileName
        objAtt.SaveAsFile SaveFolder & DateFormat & objAtt.FileName

        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(SaveFolder)

        If UCase(Right$(objAtt.FileName, Len("XML"))) = UCase("XML") Then
            NewFileName = convFolder & DateFormat & objAtt.FileName & "_conv.xlsx"

            Set ConvertThis = Workbooks.Open(SaveFolder & DateFormat & objAtt.FileName)
            ConvertThis.SaveAs FileName:=NewFileName, FileFormat:= _
            xlOpenXMLWorkbook
            ConvertThis.Close
        End If
    Next
    Set objAtt = Nothing
End Sub
```

To Test it, select the Email and run the following code

```
Public Sub Test_Rule()
    Dim Item As MailItem

    Set Item = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
    saveconvAttachtoDisk Item

    Set Item = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: I copied your code and it runs but nothing was saved in the folders.

Comment: @vega69 make sure not to mix your old code with new code, by the way how are you testing?

Comment: Yes, I updated the xml and xls folders. I replaced the old code with this new one. Which sub should I put in the Outlook rule? The "Test_Rule" or the "saveconvAttachtoDisk"?

Comment: @vega69 `Test_Rule` is  only for testing your code `saveconvAttachtoDisk` put both subs in 1 module then  select the email with xml attachment and then run  `Test_Rule` sub or run it by pressing F8 -

Comment: So did I and it is working properly. What is the next step?

Comment: @vega69 If it is working then the code is good - now Delete your old rule and re-create new rule and call 'saveconvAttachtoDisk'.